# MySQL link table with extra fields creates cartesian product

Tags: mysql, sql, django-models

I'm trying to build an app that besides recording number of sales also maintains the history between a supervisor and his/her team.

```
CREATE TABLE `emp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `tl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tlFK_idx` (`tl_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tlFK` FOREIGN KEY (`tl_id`) REFERENCES `emp` (`id`) 


CREATE TABLE `super` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `emp_super` (
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `super_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`,`super_id`,`fecha`),
  KEY `empFK_idx` (`emp_id`),
  KEY `superFK_idx` (`super_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `empsuperFK` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `emp` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `super_empFK` FOREIGN KEY (`super_id`) REFERENCES `super` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

As you can see, the table emp_super is the link table with the exception of having a date field.

```
emp_id super_id fecha
101863  101404  2012-10-15
101863  101503  2012-10-01
102403  101404  2012-10-15
102403  101503  2012-10-01
103052  101404  2012-10-15
103052  101503  2012-10-01
103718  101404  2012-10-15
103718  101503  2012-10-01
```

The key is to keep a record of when a supervisor was assigned to a group, so that when there is any change, the new supervisor would not inherit his group's performance under the previous leader.
I've been working on a query to extract the sales made by a particular group but I immediately noticed that even though I think I'm making all the right connections, I receive a Cartesian product.

Here's the sales table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sale_date` date NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `empFK_idx` (`emp_id`),
  KEY `campaignFK_idx` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `empFK` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `emp_super` (`emp_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `productFK` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Normally, when dealing with dates, I try and limit the dates to the main table my data is coming from but in this case I need to also take into account the dates for the employee-supervisor relationship.

My query so far is this:

```
SELECT s.sale_date,su.id,concat_ws(' ',su.nombre,su.apellido), p.name,e.id,concat_ws(' ',e.nombre,e.apellido), s.qty
from tracker.emp e, tracker.products p, tracker.sales s,tracker.super su, tracker.emp_super es
where e.id = es.emp_id
and su.id = es.super_id
and s.product_id = p.id
and e.id = s.emp_id
and s.sale_date between '2012-10-01' and '2012-10-15'
and es.fecha between '2012-10-01' and '2012-10-15'
order by su.id,p.name,e.id;
```

If I reduce the dates to the 14, then I receive the correct result because the other supervisor did not join until the 15.  Has anyone ever encountered this business requirement: to maintain a record of leadership so that a new leader does not inherit his predecessors achievements or mistakes?

Thank you for any suggestions you might have.

Comment: The first thing that pops into my mind is to have a field to store the date a relationship between a supervisor and worker ended.

Comment: I'm also curious about the function of field emp.tl_id.

Comment: tl_id references the relationship the employee has with a team leader.  For purposes of the question it doesn't present an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take account of when the supervisory role ended.

This will give you that but I suspect that it will not be very efficient.

```
SELECT e1.emp_id 
      ,e1.super_id
      ,e1.fecha
      ,MIN(DATEADD(DAY, -1, e2.fecha)) AS end
FROM  emp_super e1
      INNER JOIN
      emp_super e2 ON e1.emp_id=e2.emp_id 
                      AND
                      e1.fecha<e2.fecha
GROUP BY e1.emp_id 
        ,e1.super_id
        ,e1.fecha
```

Perhaps an end column on the link table updated by a `TRIGGER` would be better?

Comment: We thought as much, but ended going to a different design all together.  I'm not at work right now so I don't have the code with me, but once I can, I'll post the new design and explain how we figured it out.  I will say that for this project's purpose, maintaining historical data is not exclusively managed through the  employee-supervisor relationship. I'll post more when I have the remaining data.